# Raw use of parameterized class 'ViewManager'

Tags: java, react-native, generics

Is there a way to fix the following compiler warning in the package specification of a React Native native module?

> Raw use of parameterized class 'ViewManager'

[image: WebStorm screenshot of warning]

Full source:

```java
package com.example.foobar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class FooBarPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.singletonList(new FooBarViewManager());
    }
}
```

- Source of [`ReactPackage`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.71-stable/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactPackage.java)
- Source of [`ViewManager`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.71-stable/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/ViewManager.java)

Comment: Try supplying specific generic parameters or wildcard parameters; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Thanks @StephenC for the suggestion. I tried to use `<?>` but unfortunately it did not help. When I try to supply specific generics, I'm getting "attempting to use incompatible return types".

Comment: Well yes.  It will probably be more complicated than just adding simple wildcards.  Unfortunately we won't be able to advise you without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I've added the full source of the file, as well as links to `ReactPackage` and `ViewManager`.

Comment: You could try sidestepping the issue by using `<Object>`

Comment: Did not work either.. I'm starting to think it is not possible to fix this warning without changing the code in ReactPackage and/or ViewManager.